# The tangential gradient of a function $f$ defined on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

I'm self study Riemannian Geometry to be able to understand this [lecture notes about Mean Curvature Flow](http://www.felixschulze.eu/images/autumn_2017/notes_mcf_16112017.pdf). The first chapter is a review of Riemannian Geometry and I'm stuck in the following part:

> "Using the isomorphism induced by the metric $g$ we can regard $\nabla f$ also as element of the tangent space, in this case it is called the gradient of $f$. The gradient of $f$ can be identified with a vector in $R^{n+1}$ via the differential $dF$; such a vector is called the tangential gradient of $f$ and is denoted by $\nabla^M f$, given in coordinates
>   by"
>
> $$\nabla^M f = \nabla^i f \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} = g^{ij} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}$$
>
> The word ”tangential” comes from the equivalent definition of $\nabla^M f$ in case $f$ is a function defined on the ambient space $R^{n+1}$. It can be checked that $\nabla^M f$ is the projection of the standard Euclidean gradient $DF$ onto the tangent space of $M$, that is,
>
> $$\nabla^M f = Df - \langle Df, \nu \rangle_e \nu,$$
>
> where $\nu$ is a local choice of unit normal to $M$.

A relevant consideration done in the beginning of the chapter is

> We restrict ourselves to manifolds of codimension 1 in an Euclidean ambient
>   space, i.e. we consider a n-dimensional smooth manifold $M$, without boundary,
>   either closed or complete and non-compact and an immersion (or embedding)
>
> $$F: M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$$
>
> [...]We denote by $g_{ij} := \langle \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}. \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j} \rangle_e$ the induced metric on $M$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_e$ is the Euclidean scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

My doubt is what I need to check exactly? I need to show that $g^{ij} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i} = Df - \langle Df, \nu \rangle_e$ or I need prove that the $\textit{gradient}$ of $f$ (which is different of the definition of $\textit{tangential  gradient}$ of $f$) is equal to $Df - \langle Df, \nu \rangle_e$ identifying $\textit{gradient}$ of $f$ with the $\textit{tangential  gradient}$ of $f$? In the first case, I think the argument is just as it is in [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682004/gradient-of-a-function-restricted-to-a-submanifold?rq=1), but I don't know how to prooced if the case is the second.

Thanks in advance!

$\textbf{P.S.:}$

Other consideration that maybe be relevant: my background are Linear Algebra, Metric Spaces, Analysis on $\mathbb{R^n}$ and Differential Geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to "check" (essentially) is that
$$D \widetilde{f} \circ DF=df, $$
which is trivial by the chain rule, where I am denoting by $\widetilde{f}$ the function as defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ (so that $\widetilde{f} \circ F=f$). $^{(1)}$

Now the rest is linear algebra (which may also be considered something to "check"), since given $X_p \in T_pM$,
\begin{align*}
df(X_p)=D\widetilde{f}( DF(X_p))&=\langle \nabla \widetilde{f}, DF(X_p\rangle) \\
&=\langle (\nabla \widetilde{f})^{\perp}+(\nabla \widetilde{f})^{\top}, DF(X_p)\rangle \\
&=\langle (\nabla \widetilde{f})^{\top}, DF( X_p) \rangle \\
&=\langle DF^{-1}(\nabla \widetilde{f}^{\top}), X_p \rangle,
\end{align*}
so the gradient of $f$ at some $p \in M$ is just the tangential gradient vector  of $\widetilde{f}$ (under the identification of $DF$ $^{(2)}$). I am assuming you are giving $M$ the pull-back metric, of course.

$^{(1)}$Just an observation: There may be some identifications here, depending on definitions. If you take $Df$ to mean the usual definition as given in a standard course in analysis, then you must identify $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the usual way. This is also the difference between $df: T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$ or $df: T_pM \to T_p\mathbb{R}$, which you allude to in the comments.

$^{(2)}$This is the identification he mentions at

> The gradient of $f$ can be identified with a vector in $R^{n+1}$ via the differential $dF$.

Comment: I understand the second part assuming the first, but the first part isn't clear for me yet. First, $f$ is a map $f: M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $df_p: T_pM \longrightarrow T_{f(p)} \mathbb{R}$, right? But $F: M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then $DF: T_pM \longrightarrow T_{F(p)} F(M) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and, consequently, DF|_{T_pM} \neq df, right? I saw that you're brazilian, I'm brazilian too. I'm studying Riemannian geometry by this notes: 

http://www.mat.ufmg.br/~rodney/notas_de_aula/geometria_riemanniana.pdf

written in portuguese.

Comment: Is your definition of Xf the same as defined in these lecture notes on page $15$?

Comment: @George Good to see a fellow brazilian! : ) I will put some more details in the answer. OBS: I thought "F" just referred to the extension of $f$, so there are some clashing notations here. I'll fix them up.

Comment: Firstly, I would like to say that I understood now the first verification. Now, I have two doubts. 1) When you put $DF^{-1} \left( \nabla \overline{f} \right)^T$ you want to say $DF^{-1} \left( \left( \nabla \overline{f} \right)^T \right)$ not  $\left( DF^{-1} \left( \nabla \overline{f} \right) \right)^T$, right? 2) Essentialy, we wanted prove that $\nabla f = DF^{-1} \left( \left( \nabla \overline{f} \right)^T \right)$, right?

Comment: @George Correct for both.

Comment: I understood now, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @George in the identity you gave do you mean $\nabla^M f = \nabla f - \langle \nabla f, \nu \rangle_e$? if this is the case how we have a vector (-) scalar on L.R.H. ?

Comment: @S.Maths it's $\nabla^M f = Df - \langle Df, \nu \rangle_e \nu$.

Comment: Is $Df$ here different to $\nabla f$ (vector of partial derivative)? If they are the same, I'm a bit confused about this equality, because $\nabla^M f\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\nabla f, \nu \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: @S.Maths, $\nabla^M f$ is the tangential component of $Df \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, the usual derivative in an Euclidean space. Are you refirring $\nabla f$ as $\nabla^M f$?

Comment: For me $\nabla f:= Df$ the usual gradient. My question is that $\nabla^M f\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (as tangential vector) or $\nabla^M f\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ because in the first case the identity doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo in $\nabla^M f = Df - \langle Df, \nu \rangle_e \nu$, does $\nu$ depend on $f$?

Comment: @Migalobe No, $\nu$ depends only on $M$.